# How to determine if a field has changed in a Django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I was surprised that this was difficult to do. However I came up with this, which seems to work at least for my simple case. Can anyone recommend a better approach?

```
def field_changed(self, fieldname):
    """Tests if the value of the field changed from the original data"""
    orig_value = self.fields[fieldname].initial or getattr(self.instance, field, None)
    orig_value = getattr(orig_value, 'pk', orig_value)
    if type(orig_value) is bool:
        # because None and False can be interchangeable
        return bool(self.data.get(fieldname)) != bool(orig_value)
    else:
        return unicode(self.data.get(fieldname)) != unicode(orig_value)
```

Answer (score 56):

Form contains a property changed_data which holds a list of all the fields whose values have changed.

Try:

```
'fieldname' in myforminstance.changed_data
```

Comment: Tech note: if form field was rendered with a model field default value, which was not set before (for instance on create), then, unless the default value was changed, this field's name will not be in the `changed_data` list

Answer (score 17):

It seems that you have reinvented [`.has_changed()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.has_changed) method.

Comment: when in doubt, search the docs; or I also find inspecting the django code is a great way to find all the available methods.

Comment: Yeah, django source code is well documented and it's quite teaching in some aspects. Also good IDE helps a lot giving easy access to source code right from the project files.

Comment: Downvoting as `field.has_changed()` seems to require 2 required positional arguments: 'initial' and 'data'. This would then require the retrieval of the original form data and the new form data, at which point you might as well compare the new and old entries yourself. [Airs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43550210/10359765) is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

#### Extending on [Airs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43550210/10359765), for multiple fields:

In a scenario where you'd like to track changes for a list of fields `['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c']`

---

If you'd like to check if *any* of those fields has changed:

```py
any(x in myforminstance.changed_data for x in ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c'])
```

---

If you'd like to check if *all* of those fields have changed:

```py
all(x in myforminstance.changed_data for x in ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You must override the method `post_save`. Overriding methods is a good practice in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save

I suggest you adding something like this into your model class:

```
    def post_save(self, sender, instance, created, raw, using, update_fields):
        if 'the_field' in update_fields:
           # Do whatever...
```

Comment: The point of a signal is not to override but to listen for the signal

Comment: `update_fields` doesn't list fields that have changed, it only lists fields passed to `update_fields` on the `save()` method.  So a field may change without it being included in `update_fields`.

Comment: Can you still use any of the parameters available in `post_save` to make sure?

Comment: the post_save function sign should include **kwargs so (sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs) will work as post_save parameters